# Is it a bug or deferred execution? -3 + 1= -1?

Tags: discussion, bug, voting, votes

I have asked a question, which was put on hold for whatever reason(allegedly it's too broad).. It was also **3 x downvoted** So I have also tried to improve the question to make less scope to mark the question as too broad. I have noticed, that the question become **1 upvote**. My expectation was, that the question will have **-2** vote. But it has **-1**! Why? Is it a bug or just deferred execution?

Enclosed the screenshots:
[image: reputation]
[image: question]

Or the question itself :
[Commonly used/standardized symbols for client and server representation [on hold]](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/366673/commonly-used-standardized-symbols-for-client-and-server-representation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are currently two downvotes and one upvote on your question. This could have happened if someone removed their downvote, or if someone flipped their downvote into an upvote.

Usually, votes are locked in and cannot be changed at will, except for a grace period after casting the vote, or after the post was edited. That is supposed to encourage meaningful edits, not just changing which words are bold.

Comment: +1, but _"if someone removed their downvote, or if someone flipped their downvote into an upvote"_ Shouldn't then the -2 from downvote disappear? I see now: 3x(-2) + 1x(+5) + 1x(+5) + 1x(-2).

Comment: @Rekshino I don't think the reputation timeline shows *all* events, in particular not when votes are removed. While Stack Exchange is very open, quite a lot of data particularly about votes is kept secret. Yes, retracting a downvote should also remove the -2, this effect would be visible in your achievement inbox.

Comment: But I don't see the removal of -2(it is also reflected in reputation). Only +5 and actions from today(+5 and -2). Or do I not understand something?

Comment: @Rekshino you are right, the question score doesn't line up with your reputation. There is a downvote that doesn't exist. In this case, that might be due to a rare edge case: when a user is deleted, their votes are undone. However, the reputation effect of their votes is not always reverted, depending on how and why the account is removed.